Adroid studio Koala no longer creates armeabi-v7a debug symbols
I have an app bundle on Google Play and am updating my Android project in the latest Android Studio (Koala) to the latest API as required by Google.
However, when looking to upload the debug symbols, I noticed that the path to them slightly changed and that the project generates only arm64-v8a. Now, the Play Console warns me that this will cause a drop in support for thousands of (probably old) devices due to incompatible ABI.
Is there any way I can force the support of the older ABIs?
In the build.gradle(app) i have ndk {abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'} but still only the arm64-v8a gets created.
